# NameError in Discussions#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nomethoderror

Im trying to write an ruby app that lets you post discussions and comment on posts.  The issue is that I cant get the comments- here called microposts, to show up below the discussions.  Right now, im getting the error NameError in Discussions#index: undefined local variable or method `discussion' for #<#:0x0000010563a1e0>.  Any ideas?

the micropost form

```
<% @micropost = Micropost.new %>

<%= form_for(@micropost) do |f| %>
    <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "Compose new micropost..." %>
    </div>
    <%= f.hidden_field :discussion_id, discussion.id%>

    <%= f.submit "Post", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

micropost controller

```
class MicropostsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :signed_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]

  def index
  end

  def create
    @discussion = current_user.discussions.new
    @micropost = current_user.microposts.build(params[:micropost])
     if @micropost.save
       flash[:success] = "Posted!"
       redirect_to root_url
     else
       render 'static_pages/home'
     end
  end

  def destroy
  end
end
```

discussion controller

```
class DiscussionsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :signed_in_user, only: [:index, :edit, :update]


  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @discussions = @user.discussion.paginate(page: params[:page])
    @microposts = @user.micropost.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

  def index
    @discussions = Discussion.all
  end

  def create
    @discussion = current_user.discussions.build(params[:discussion])
    if @discussion.save
      flash[:success] = "Discussion Started!"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render 'static_pages/home'
    end
  end

  def destroy
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
  end

  def new
  end
end
```

discussion view

```
<% content_for :script do %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'hover_content' %>
<% end %>

<li>
  <div class = "intro-bar"><span class = "intro"><%=discussion.intro %></span></div>
  <div class = "content-bar">
    <span class = "content"><%= discussion.content %></span>
    <div class = "buttons">
      <div class = "vote-neg"><%= link_to "Break Up", signup_path,class: "btn btn-large btn-breakup" %></div>
      <div class = "vote-plus"><%= link_to "Stay Together", signup_path,class: "btn btn-large btn-staytogether" %></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>

<span class = "timestamp">
    Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(discussion.created_at) %> ago.
  </span>

<div class = "comments">
  <% discussion.microposts.each do |micropost| %>
      <li>
        <div class = "post-comment"><%= micropost.content%></div>
      </li>
  <% end %>
</div>

<% if signed_in? %>
    <div class = "row">
      <aside class = "span4">
        <section>
          <%= render 'shared/micropost_form', :locals => {:discussion => discussion }%>
        </section>
      </aside>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

thanks for the help, im sure its something really simple.  Im quite new at this

Comment: where is the discussion variable that is used in your view defined? you can use the instance variables from your controller action in your view. You probably want to use @discussions

Comment: i guess it hasnt been defined properly.  what would the proper code be to define it?  discussion = Discussion.find(params[:id]) ?  and where would i put it?

Comment: You can put it in your controller action as `@discussion = Discussion.find(params[:id])` and use @discussion in your view

Comment: the issue there being for def show in the discussion controller i already have @discussions = @user.discussion.paginate(page: params[:page]).

Answer (score 0):

In this code,

```
class DiscussionsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :signed_in_user, only: [:index, :edit, :update]


  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @discussions = @user.discussion.paginate(page: params[:page])
    @microposts = @user.micropost.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end
```

it looks like `@user.discussion` is your problem. Should probably be `@user.discussions`. Likewise with the next line, `@user.microposts`

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you show discussion with `show` method. But, in show method and everywhere else in controller except `create` you declare `@discussions`.

I actually can't get, why in show method you do what suits more for index method, but anyway, Rails pass variable from controller to views if it is declared as instance (with `@`).

So, to define variale in views, you should have `@discussion` in relative controller method, and locals should also pass `@discussion`:

```
:locals => {:discussion => @discussion }
```

Comment: thanks for the help!  sorry, like i said, im still quite new at this.  where should i put that line of code?

Comment: where you render micropost partial. But there is also other issues, as far as I can see.

Comment: i put it in as 
<div class = "post-comment"><%= micropost.content> :locals => {:discussion => @discussion } %></div>
and still getting an issue.  also, what other issues?

Comment: @user2472006, if you have read all my answer, I sad that you need to declare `@discussion` in controller method.

Comment: im sorry, im not quite sure what to declare it as

Comment: @user2472006, show method in way it makes sense should display one particular discussion, which has microblog form for this particular discussion.